Hello, I just switched to Ubuntu and some textures are broken
I just switched to Ubuntu and some textures are broken. As in the link I sent you, textures are broken in Ubuntu's own applications, but these do not happen in 3rd party applications. here is the video: https://streamable.com/ama143

Are you using NVidia graphics? Please provide more information about your computer model by editing the question

You do realize this is a user-support site; so if you're wanting to report a bug you need to report this on a bug tracker. Your title & details provide a statement, without an actual problem you're asking us other users to solve?  What do you want help with? For bug reporting please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and report on a bug tracker (this is a Stack Exchange user support site)
